# ¿Por que se detiene mi app en modo release, pero no en modo debug?

Tags: pdf, flutter

Estoy utilizando una librería para visualizar un PDF ([flutter_pdfview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview)) el cual no hasta ahora no me causaba problemas.

- Actualmente probé la aplicación para realizar unas actualizaciones, en modo **debug** funciona todo bien.
- Ahora genero el apk con `flutter build apk`, instalo la app en mi teléfono y al entrar a visualizar el PDF la app se cierra.

para intentar encontrar el error he intentado ejecutar `flutter run --release`, esto ocasiona que mi teléfono se reinicie pero después de 3 o 4 intentos se pudo ejecutar y funciona perfectamente

*Por si acaso,  algunas soluciones y lo que dice la documentación mencionan el uso de **proguard** el cual no uso, o por lo menos no esta en mi  archivo **build.gradle***

---

Gracias al comentario, puede obtener el log en el cual muestra lo siguiente (solo coloco la parte donde muestra el error ya que lo demás no creo que sea relevante).

```
2020-06-11 10:15:42.105 12785-12838/? D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xcc79bb90, 0xcaf7e008
2020-06-11 10:15:42.107 12785-12852/? D/jniPdfium: Init FPDF library
2020-06-11 10:15:42.108 12785-12785/? D/ViewRootImpl@5b60fda[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1680) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
2020-06-11 10:15:42.128 4363-9699/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{5e42c8c u0 Sys2030:mx.com.publicacioneselfaro.himnia_musica/mx.com.publicacioneselfaro.himnia_musica.MainActivity} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_class == null
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]     in call to GetMethodID
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]     from com.shockwave.pdfium.a.a com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeGetPageSizeByIndex(long, int, int)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=21 Runnable
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12e0b1b0 self=0xe4452a00
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | sysTid=12852 nice=10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xcab09970
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=5 core=3 HZ=100
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | stack=0xcaa07000-0xcaa09000 stackSize=1038KB
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #00 pc 002eedcf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+130)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #01 pc 003844db  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+206)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.376 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #02 pc 00380a57  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+34)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #03 pc 0025187f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+738)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #04 pc 00251c6b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+66)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #05 pc 00286c8b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::GetMethodID(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*)+994)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #06 pc 000037d7  /data/app/mx.com.publicacioneselfaro.himnia_musica-heck9rZ6EQdvqxG_4m-dkA==/lib/arm/libjniPdfium.so (Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeGetPageSizeByIndex+134)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #07 pc 0000046d  /data/app/mx.com.publicacioneselfaro.himnia_musica-heck9rZ6EQdvqxG_4m-dkA==/oat/arm/base.odex (Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeGetPageSizeByIndex__JII+100)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeGetPageSizeByIndex(Native method)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.b(:251)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   - locked <0x0d28c339> (a java.lang.Object)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at c.a.a.a.i.b(:93)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at c.a.a.a.i.<init>(:82)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at c.a.a.a.c.a(:51)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at c.a.a.a.c.doInBackground(:25)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] 
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:542] Runtime aborting...
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:542] 
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_class == null
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]     in call to GetMethodID
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]     from com.shockwave.pdfium.a.a com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeGetPageSizeByIndex(long, int, int)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550] "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=21 Runnable
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12e0b1b0 self=0xe4452a00
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   | sysTid=12852 nice=10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xcab09970
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=5 core=3 HZ=100
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   | stack=0xcaa07000-0xcaa09000 stackSize=1038KB
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   native: #00 pc 002eedcf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+130)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   native: #01 pc 003844db  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+206)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   native: #02 pc 00380a57  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+34)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   native: #03 pc 0025187f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+738)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   native: #04 pc 00251c6b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+66)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   native: #05 pc 00286c8b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::GetMethodID(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*)+994)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   native: #06 pc 000037d7  /data/app/mx.com.publicacioneselfaro.himnia_musica-heck9rZ6EQdvqxG_4m-dkA==/lib/arm/libjniPdfium.so (Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeGetPageSizeByIndex+134)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   native: #07 pc 0000046d  /data/app/mx.com.publicacioneselfaro.himnia_musica-heck9rZ6EQdvqxG_4m-dkA==/oat/arm/base.odex (Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeGetPageSizeByIndex__JII+100)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeGetPageSizeByIndex(Native method)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.b(:251)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   - locked <0x0d28c339> (a java.lang.Object)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at c.a.a.a.i.b(:93)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at c.a.a.a.i.<init>(:82)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at c.a.a.a.c.a(:51)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at c.a.a.a.c.doInBackground(:25)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550] 
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-06-11 10:15:42.378 12785-12852/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 12852 (AsyncTask #1), pid 12785 (o.himnia_musica)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.377 12785-12852/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:550] 
2020-06-11 10:15:42.475 12855-12855/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
2020-06-11 10:15:42.477 4120-4120/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 12785
2020-06-11 10:15:42.479 12855-12855/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 12785 (target tid = 12852)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.480 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2020-06-11 10:15:42.480 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/on7xelteub/on7xelte:8.1.0/M1AJQ/G610MUBS7CTA2:user/release-keys'
2020-06-11 10:15:42.480 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '4'
2020-06-11 10:15:42.480 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2020-06-11 10:15:42.480 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG: pid: 12785, tid: 12852, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> mx.com.publicacioneselfaro.himnia_musica <<<
2020-06-11 10:15:42.480 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2020-06-11 10:15:42.485 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_class == null'
2020-06-11 10:15:42.485 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00003234  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
2020-06-11 10:15:42.485 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     r4 000031f1  r5 00003234  r6 cab086ec  r7 0000010c
2020-06-11 10:15:42.485 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     r8 00000000  r9 cab08739  sl 0000000a  fp cab08738
2020-06-11 10:15:42.485 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     ip c939aa20  sp cab086d8  lr f0544e6f  pc f053e528  cpsr 200f0030
2020-06-11 10:15:42.489 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2020-06-11 10:15:42.489 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0001a528  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+63)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.489 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00365cd3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+402)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.489 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 004276e7  /system/lib/libart.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+454)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.489 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00251a75  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1240)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.489 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00251c6b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+66)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.489 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00286c8b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::GetMethodID(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*)+994)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.489 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000037d7  /data/app/mx.com.publicacioneselfaro.himnia_musica-heck9rZ6EQdvqxG_4m-dkA==/lib/arm/libjniPdfium.so (Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeGetPageSizeByIndex+134)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.489 12855-12855/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000f46d  /data/app/mx.com.publicacioneselfaro.himnia_musica-heck9rZ6EQdvqxG_4m-dkA==/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0xf000)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.513 5448-5448/? D/io_stats: !@ 179,0 r 1549150 49420340 w 546257 10574324 d 82329 5077248 f 123355 123290 iot 1416740 1392264 th 51200 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 47039.532
2020-06-11 10:15:42.749 2613-8893/? I/display: [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(0)
2020-06-11 10:15:42.989 4363-4511/? D/WifiTrafficPoller: TrafficStats TxPkts=393208 RxPkts=1067699 TxBytes=98352287 RxBytes=1311285470 , Foreground uid=10553 pkgName=mx.com.publicacioneselfaro.himnia_musica txBytes=118744 rxBytes=9876941
2020-06-11 10:15:42.991 4790-4991/? D/Tile.WifiTile: handleUpdateState enabled  = true
2020-06-11 10:15:43.575 9959-10020/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database '+data+user+0+com_microsoft_launcher+databases+AriaStorage_db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 3332 (Aria-Stats-thread-1) with flags 0x2 for 16126.857 seconds.
    Connections: 0 active, 1 idle, 0 available.
```

Comment: sí, conecta tu android device,  abre android studio, cualquier proyecto, solo necesitas revisar el LOGCAT, ahí puedes ver el error en release mode, una vez que tengas el log  actualizas tu pregunta

Comment: @diegoveloper gracias por las instrucciones, tal como lo indicaste edité la pregunta con la información proporcionada por el **LogCat**, e indicando lo que  ya revise sobre el `proGuard`

Comment: que tal si agregas la lineas donde te da el error? faltaria eso para ser una pregunta completa

Comment: estás usando proguard?

Comment: @JackNavaRow No agregue las lineas de código que uso para ver el pdf, por que básicamente son las mismas que en la documentación, aparte de que no son las causantes del error, esta app funcionaba correctamente e incluso se subió a playStore, se actualizo flutter y se cambiaron algunas cosas sin tocar lo del PDF, al hacer pruebas fue que ya no funciono para esta nueva actualización de la app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que mencionas se debe a `proguard`, está ofuscando las clases incluso del plugin.

Sigue este link para configurar `proguard` : https://flutter-es.io/docs/deployment/android#paso-1---configurar-proguard

> Crea el archivo /android/app/proguard-rules.pro y añade las reglas
> listadas a continuación.

En el archivo agrega lo siguiente:

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }

#Aquí lo que indica el plugin
-keep class com.shockwave.**
```

Con eso se debería solucionar el problema

Comment: Ok, entonces tengo que agrega también `useProguard true` en mi **build.gradle**. correcto ? o solo el puro archivo ?

Comment: sí, agrega esas lineas q menciona :  useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'